# Crear registro en una tabla con relación many to many Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Estoy creando una Api Rest con Spring Boot.

Tengo dos tablas (`libros`) y (`autores`) que comparten una relación muchos a muchos (`libros_autores`).

¿Cómo inserto un registro en la tabla (`libros_autores`), en caso que el autor no exista, teniendo en cuenta que en el mismo formulario donde se crean los libros hay un botón para crear autores nuevos?

¿Cómo hago para enviar un Json del libro a crear, donde vayan anidados los autores y autor que no exista se cree, sin conocer todavía el id del libro al que pertenece?

Comment: Aquí lo explican claramente ese ejemplo con jpa https://www.oscarblancarteblog.com/2018/12/27/relaciones-manytomany/

Comment: Hey gracias, voy a revisarlo